# How does sonarQube calculate technical debt

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

In the new version of sonarqube, the documntation states that technical debt (TD)

```
TD= Effort to fix all maintainability issues. The measure is stored in minutes in the DB. An 8-hour day is assumed when values are shown in days.
```

However, how does sonarqube measure maintainability issues?

Answer (score 9):

Each rule that detects an issue in SonarQube has a remediation effort function. This remediation function is visible on the description page of each rule:

[image]

This remediation effort is used to compute the technical debt of every code smell (= maintainability issues).

The technical debt of a project is the simply the sum of the technical debt of every code smell in the project (which means that bugs and vulnerabilities don't contribute to the technical debt).

Comment: In an older version (or maybe it was a plugin...), technical debt was a function of the time to fix issues as you describe, but also a function of test coverage and duplication. There was even a pie graph showing how these factors would influence the debt. So, **test coverage** and **duplication** are not part of the technical debt calculation anymore?